# React Native: Modal or react-navigation for showing modals

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

native, Modal is like a pop up which obscures everything bellow, according to react navigation docs in order to show your full screen/or not modals you can make use of nested navigators and mode prop in navigator:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/

Recently I just found there's also the Modal react-native component, so my question is, what should I use for modals? Navigate to them or isVisible prop with Modal element. For now I think I'll use navigation for more native feel but I wanted to know what you guys think.